# Problems getting RabbitMQ and Django-Celery Running: Target Machine actively refused connection

Tags: django, firewall, rabbitmq, celery

I am trying to get Django-Celery running on my Django App. I cannot get the worker server to run. When I try I get the message: **No Connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**

Here is what I have done so far. First, I installed the django celery package: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery

I can load it into python without problems. I also installed the RabbitMQ server per the windows install instructions: http://www.rabbitmq.com/install.html#windows

Starting the tutorials in pytho on the RabbitMQ site I saw the need to install pika: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pika. It imports without any problems.

From there I start the RabbitMQ server by running this at the command line: `rabbitmq-service start`

I get the message back that `Service RabbitMQ started`

Here is where I start to have problems.

I attempted the first steps in django-celery: http://packages.python.org/django-celery/getting-started/first-steps-with-django.html and the "hello world" example on the rabbitMQ site: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html

In both cases I get the message: **No Connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**

My first thought was that this sounded like a firewall problem. So I went into the windows 7 firewall and added inbound and outbound rules to open the local and remote ports 5672 and 5673 to TCP protocol, but I still get the same error message.

When I run `rabbitmqctl status` i get the message: 
    **Error: unable to connect to node 'rabbit@hostname': nodedown

    diagnostics:

    - nodes and their ports on hostname: [{rabbitmqctl18856, 505031}]**

Does that mean it that it is trying to operate on those ports? what about the default 5672?

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** This was actually a problem resulting from several failed rabbitmq installs conflicting with the latest installation. If you have to remove rabbitmq use the 'rabbitmq-service remove' command and not SC DELETE, which cause a lot of problems for me and I had to go in and clean up my windows registry file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nodedown` error indicated by rabbitmqctl suggests that the server isn't running on that machine.

Try going though the steps in RabbitMQ's [troubleshooting guide](http://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting.html).  In particular, pay close attention to the logs.  Has the server crashed for some reason?  Could you post the logs somewhere?